# dns_get_record during a foreach

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop through a text file and find the ip address of all the domains, when I pass a single domain name to dns_get_record it works fine but when I do it through a for_each I get an error of array().

I'm certain it's something simple, but I cant for the life of me see it, code below any help appreciated.

```
<?php
$names = file('sites.txt');

foreach ($names as $name) {
   $name1 = "www.google.co.uk";
   $result = dns_get_record($name, DNS_A);
   echo $name;
   print_r($result);
   echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: "An error of array"‽ Please show the actual error message.

Comment: If `file` fails, it returns `false` which will result in the `foreach` loop to not work. Give more detailed error messages and we could help you. My guess is that `sites.txt` is either not existing or not readable.

Comment: Hiya,

fixed it, the fixed code looks like:

    <?php
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',true);
    $names = file('sites.txt');
    
    foreach ($names as $name) {
    
    $result = dns_get_record(trim($name), DNS_A);
    echo $name;
    print_r($result);
    echo "<br>";
      }
    
    ?>